# Why Twisted Manhole ConnectionDone is an error?

Tags: python, twisted

I'm using twisted manhole (https://github.com/HoverHell/pyaux/blob/master/pyaux/runlib.py#L126), and I also send errors caught by Twisted into python logging (https://github.com/HoverHell/pyaux/blob/master/pyaux/twisted_aux.py#L9).

However, as a result, the log gets `ConnectionDone()` errors, which isn't a very interesting thing as an *error*.

What would be appropriate to change to avoid getting this (and, possibly, some other) not-exactly-errors? Filtering for `twisted.python.failure.Failure` cases, perhaps? And where from is the ConnectionDone() even raised and why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ConnectionDone() instance is given to connectionLost() callback after the connection has been closed. You should be seeing this, when the client side decides to close the connection. 
You definitely don't want to filter the Failure out. You can think of the failure as a "asynchronous analogy" of the Exception. The usual thing to do, not to see some kind of exceptions is something like:

```
from twisted.internet import error

...

def connectionLost(self, reason):
    if reason.check(error.ConnectionDone):
        # this is normal, ignore this
        pass
    else:
        # do whatever you have been doing for logging
```

Comment: Is ConnectionDone the only such special case, or there are some others?

Comment: There is also ConnectionLost is used when connection is closed in non-clean manner. These are used by twisted itself for all the protocols. Reason may also be somethign specific to the protocol you are using, this depends on the implementation itself.

Comment: It's `error`, though, not `errors`. Anyway, subclassing TelnetTransport with that helps; but really, I can't imagine the reason for the http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/conch/telnet.py?rev=37018#L591 part (options processing on connectionLost? huh)

Comment: Options is not the perfect choice of the variable name there... They represent the effect of negotiation. Depending on that, each side of the connection might be or not notified about the connection termination. This is what that code is doing... I've seen *much* worse.